# Background color of UITableViewCell's header

Tags: ios, uitableview, uilabel

I'd like to make the `backgroundColor` of a `UITableView`'s section header view **transparent**.  I don't want to format the text in the header because I like the default formatting.  Can I do this with:

```
-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView 
            viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

without having to format the text in a `UILabel`?  Everything I've tried covers up the text in the section header (that I get from `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`) and I don't know how to format the text myself.

Comment: Why do you fear formatting the text in UILabel?

Comment: Just don't want to spend the time :-)  I'm looking for the default text color, shadow, indentation, font size etc.  Would be nice to just keep the defaults.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, table cells do not have a header.

The `UITableView`'s section header is an independent view.

And yes,

```
-(UIView*) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is THE table delegate method to implement. It returns a UIView (derivate) that displays the table header.

Make sure that you implement

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

as well and return the appropriate height for each header. (Probably just a constant value)

Comment: Corrected to `UITableView`'s section header 8-)

Comment: Well, now that you rephrased the question it is more clear to me.

No, viewForHeaderInSection does not change the default appearance. That method provides a full view that replaces the default appearance of the section's header.

I am afraid if you like the default design (strange though :) then you will have to align your own design with the default one. 

AFAIK viewForHeaderInSection is the only way of changing anything to the section's header

Answer (score 0):

You can use the existing default headers `UITableViewHeaderFooterView` and change values of it. This way you don't have to create the TextLabel yourself and can still use `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:`

Be Sure to register the reuseIdentifyer first with:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class] forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier:@"header"];
```

Example:

```
 - (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = [tableView dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier:@"header"];
    header.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    header.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    return header;
}
```